# Convert Scanned PDF or tessaract searchable PDF to docx/doc and maintaing all formats and layouts using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-tesseract, pdfminer

Need to convert the scanned pdf to docx document .The approach I have used so far
1.Converting the scanned pdf to Searchable pdf using pytessaract  pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr()
2. then convert that searchable pdf to docx using lowriter  'lowriter --invisible --convert-to docx"{}"

But this results to formatting and layout issue in the docx /doc and there is a overlapping of text and image in resultant docx file.
Please help

Comment: This is the best way I found out for OCR conversion while preserving the formatting: https://github.com/kmrambo/Performing-OCR-on-scanned-pdf-documents-using-Adobe-Document-Cloud-SDK

Comment: This is with cloud adobe .Is there a way to do this thing without using any cloud engine

Comment: On my personal experience, If you want to preserve all formats in the converted document,  I have never found a better way that this. You can also use pypdf to extract all the text inside the pdf and then write the text back to a docx. But this method will loose all the formatting of the native document

Comment: Actually the pdf is of scanned invoices it also has the logos, stamps ,signatures and text so need to preserve all the things with layout and formatting in the docx file .

Comment: When I talk about formatting, it is on the same lines as you described. i.e all the logos, signatures etc would be preserved

Answer (score 1):

you can use pythons, pdfminer to convert your pdf to txt, this will be better than tesseract in terms of memory, it takes in al text data, but loses formatting, you can then convert this txt file to Docx using python-Docx

```
from docx import Document
import re
import os

path = 'your path'
direct = os.listdir(path)

for i in direct:
    document = Document()
    document.add_heading(i, 0)
    myfile = open('/path/to/read/from/'+i).read()
    myfile = re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+|\x0c',' ', myfile) # remove all non-XML-compatible 
  characters
    p = document.add_paragraph(myfile)
    document.save('/path/to/write/to/'+i+'.docx')
```

or maybe you can convert the document to XML and read that way, you probably can sav the formatting to by comparing the font sizes,

GroupDocs.Conversion Cloud, offers Python SDK for Text/PDF to DOC/DOCX conversion and many other common files formats from one format to another, without depending on any third-party tool or software.

Comment: There are images in the scanned pdf also .as scanned pdf is pdf from invoices so txt file is not able to handle that images content. I agree from extracting text pdfminer will work. but if there is a image in pdf it won't work